# Users belong to organisations and only see/edit items added by their company Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Trying to figure out the best way of organising users into organisations so that the members of each organisation only see items added by themselves and other people from their organisation. All users need to use a shared login.

I have some previous experience with Devise so would like to use it if possible.

What is the best way of tackling this issue?

Any links to tutorials explaining this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked Pundit or Cancancan gems?

Comment: First you have to create rails application, SO do not provide which tutorial sites or books will help you.

Comment: I have used Cancancan before but I'm a little confused as to the logic behind what I need to do.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Yes I have my rails app setup, I  just need to tackle the company login and restricting views for each company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have user model that belongs to some company:

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :company
  ....
end
```

company model has many users and has many products(items):

```
class Company < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :products
end
```

product model that belongs to company:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :company
  ....
end
```

In your case, what you're trying to achieve is that user can see/edit only products from his company. Using before_action in your controller you can define what user can/cannot do. Here is the basic example:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:show, :edit]

  def show  
  end

  def edit 
  end

  private
  def authorize_user
   raise "Not Authorized" unless current_user.company_id == @product.company_id
  end
end
```

This way you will raise an error whenever user try to access the product that doesn't belongs to his company.

Ofcourse, this is just basic example, you should take a look on Pundit gem which is very powerful, but you should get the point with this :)

Let me know if I missed something.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. When I set up the company model do I need to include a reference to other tables in the db?

Comment: It feels like there should be a reference in the table to products or users

Comment: you have to have references in `products` & `users` tables to `company` aka foreign_key `company_id`. And that's it

Comment: Check how to write migration with foreign_key references, I didn't include that in my answer as that wasn't the original question. Whole point of authorization is in `authorize_user` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this @zauzaj